# How can I fine-tune a language model with negative examples using SFTTrainer?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, fine-tuning

I'm using the SFTTrainer from the 'trl' package to fine-tune a language model. I would like to give it some negative examples, but I'm not seeing any built-in methods anywhere. Is there something I'm missing, or some way of implementing this in a custom way?

I tried looking in the documentation but haven't seen anything obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFTTrainer is designed for supervised fine-tuning (maximizing likelihood of in-distribution samples), so there is no straightforward way to utilize negative samples.

May be other alignment algorithms like KTO([also implemented in trl](https://huggingface.co/docs/trl/main/en/kto_trainer)) would do the job in your case.

Another possible way is to modify prompt to include negative label in it. For example "{question} This is the wrong answer: {answer}".